# Remove the blank entries in line graph SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, linegraph

Hello as of now I have developed an SSRS report which is as below

[image]

As can be seen from graph, for the year 2018, the line drops to ZERO after 38/39 point but the data for that rows in NULL.

To remove that line, I have tried to set CustomAttributes to EmptyPoints=Zero, but that did not work.

The end result should be something like this, it should not display the data whose value is NULL

[image]

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: how about you edit your data set to exclude NULL???

Comment: I have tried that as well, but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

How about you apply your filter at the graph to exclude records that have a NULL value for the column. The NULLS on the database can be matched against the column using the IsNothing() function in SSRS which returns a true if the record contains a NULL for the column field being passed.

Comment: Hi Kashyap
Thanks for your reply. I have tried to check IsNothing() on Series level, but that too didn't work. I think that this is not possible in line graph at all in SSRS